# Include of non-modular header inside framework module

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am pretty new to Xcode and have been having an issue with using a framework I am using through `CocoaPods`. Everything was working fine in Xcode 7.0.1, but after I updated to Xcode 7.1 I have been having this problem. I have a pod using `ZTDropDownTextField` but when I try to build the project I get the error:

> "Include of non-modular header inside framework module
>   `ZTDropDownTextField.ZTDropDownTextField_Bridging_Header`"

and also the error:

> "could not build Objective-C module `ZTDropDownTextField`".

I have attempted setting `Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules` to `YES`, but to no avail. Does anyone know a way to fix this? It would be greatly appreciated to get some help with this.

Here's a link to a project that demonstrates the error:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/so07dd6v0ss5b0q/AACpeU3rL51dqEn5Vuqsfr1Ta?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that your framework respectively the include header search paths are not setup correctly. See this thread in the Apple Developer forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23554.

The gist of it is

*"Unfortunately, CocoaPods can commonly create header search paths that let the compiler find headers at a location which does not appear (to the compiler) to be a part of a module."*